# Guardar a través de macro vba

Tags: vba, macros

Tengo una macro para guardar un fichero en una ruta. La macro con formato XLSM la quiero guardar en una unidad de red, al ejecutarla me devuelve error y no sé por donde pillarla (he puesto el escritorio pero me pasa lo mismo, me da error en la linea ActiveWorkbook...

```
Sub guardado()
   Dim SaveName As String
   SaveName = ActiveSheet.Range("N1").Text
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Desktop\" & _
       SaveName & ".xls"
```

End Sub

Comment: ¿Cuál es el valor de `SaveName` cuando da error? También puede ser que de error porque la ruta C:\Users\Desktop\ no exista. o no tengas permisos para escribir en esa ruta. De hecho, posiblemente la ruta sea algo en plan `C:\Users\NombreUsuario\Desktop\`

Comment: Si, el valor de la ruta la falta el usuario, solo lo he omitido. Da error 1004

Comment: Vuelvo a repetir mi pregunta. ¿Cuál es el valor de `SaveName` cuando ejecutas la macro? depúralo paso a paso con F8 y mira el valor cuando falla.

Comment: ok, lo miro y te digo, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Segun lo que veo en tu codigo, te hace falta cerrar el documento para que pueda ser guardado por completo, esto permite modificarlo e includo terminar de guardarlo:

```
Sub guardado()
    Dim SaveName As String
    SaveName = ActiveSheet.Range("N1").Text
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Desktop\" & _
                                    SaveName & ".xls"
    ActiveWorckBook.Close() ''ESTA LINEA ES LA QUE TE FALTA
End Sub
```

Con esto finalizas el uso del objeto que representa el archivo en el codigo de vba.